# How to inject html tags inside $block->getHtml() in magento 2

Tags: php, magento2

I have a template where I have $block->getHtml($_item) and I want to inject some data insto this html that is returned from getHtml(). The html I get returned is below:

```
<tr>
    <td class="item-info" style="font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; vertical-align: top;">
        <p class="product-name" style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 10px;">Crown Summit Backpack</p>
        <p class="sku" style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 10px;">Artikuls: 24-MB03</p>
    </td>
    <td class="item-qty" style="font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; vertical-align: top;">1</td>
    <td class="item-price" style="font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; vertical-align: top;">
        
        <span class="price">30,00&nbsp;€</span>
    

    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to inject some `<p>` tags inside of first `<td class="item-info">`

How can I do that?

My code is below:

```
 <?php foreach ($_invoice->getAllItems() as $_item) : ?>
            <?php if (!$_item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) : ?>
                <tbody>
                    <?= $block->getItemHtml($_item); ?>
                    <p>
                        <?= $_item->getOrderItem()['manufacturers_code'];?>
                        <?= $_item->getOrderItem()['initial_delivery_date']; ?>
                        <?= $_item->getOrderItem()['qty_invoiced']; ?>
                        <?= $_item->getOrderItem()['base_price']; ?>

                    </p>
                </tbody>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Are you familiar with Magento 2 module development? (would make the answer way shorter)

Comment: @L.Gerhardt Yes, I am.

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell me the Block class and/or the template file name? Here's a link on how to enable the template path hints in developer mode: [Official Magento Documentation](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/template-path-hints.html)
You can enable hints for the template file and Block class there. From there on, I might be able to help you overwrite the child template or ItemRenderer used in the getItemHtml() method.